# Different import data commands in R

Tags: r, import

I know that there are many different ways to import data into R. And some of those in R base (e.g. read.csv, write.table etc.) just differ bei their default settings. Long time ago, I read (I cannot find the article again) that for certain circumstances some of these commands are more recommended, and one criterion was size (read.table - read.delim - read.csv - scan and fread for very large datasets). Is this true? Or something wrong in my mind? Cheers,
Nadine

Comment: `vroom` https://github.com/tidyverse/vroom

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to read in the data all at once and run functions on the data right away then use `data.table::fread`. Or else look into using the `vroom` function that is in `tidyverse`.

I'll share the `vroom` link up in the comments in case in the future the link is changed.